# Why does "make distcheck" fail on this very basic "Hello, World!" autotools example?

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools

When running "make distcheck" for the small "Hello, World!" example described below, I get error messages

```
ERROR: files left in build directory after distclean:
./install-sh
./depcomp
./missing
```

Why are those error messages generated?  Why don't the autotools cause those files to be removed?

I'm using GNU autoconf 2.69 and GNU automake 1.13.4 on GNU/Linux (Fedora) 3.18.5-101.fc20.x86_64.

**EDIT 2015-02-17:** I get the same behavior also for the am-hello example described at https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Creating-amhello.  That description implies that the error messages should not be generated.

configure.ac contains:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([hello], [1.0], [bugs@my.domain])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/hello.cc])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am contains:

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

src/Makefile.am contains:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.cc
```

src/hello.cc contains:

```
#include <iostream>             // for cout

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Files NEWS, README, AUTHORS, and ChangeLog exist but are empty.

Execute "autoreconf --install" to generate the "configure" script.  Then execute "./configure" to generate the Makefiles.  Then execute "make distcheck" to see if the package is ready for distribution.  I get error messages

```
ERROR: files left in build directory after distclean:
./install-sh
./depcomp
./missing
```

If I follow this up by running "autoreconf" and "make distcheck" again, then no error messages are generated.

**EDIT 2015-02-21**: I cannot reproduce the problem anymore on the system where I first noticed it.  I accepted some package updates since the time when I noticed the problem, but no updates to automake or autoconf were included.  The system is now at 3.18.7-100.fc20.x86_64.  I can still reproduce the problem on a different system, a clone of the first one but without the latest package updates.  That one is currently at 3.18.6-100.fc20.x86_64.  The MD5 checksums of the mentioned files are the same on both systems.  I ran "autoreconf --install -v -d > autoreconf.log 2>&1" on both systems and compared the resulting autoreconf.log files.  There are differences, but they don't mean anything to me.  The same version numbers are reported in both cases for autoconf (2.69), autoheader (2.69), automake (1.13.4), aclocal (1.13.4), autopoint (0.18.3), and libtoolize (2.4.2).  I did notice earlier on the original system (when the problem was still reproducible there) that the "depcomp", "install-sh", and "missing" files were then written to the *parent* directory of the package main directory, as if AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([..]) were included in configure.ac -- which it wasn't.  The workaround was to add AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([auxiliary]) to configure.ac (maybe AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.]) would work, too).

Comment: I think your `Makefile.am` template is missing something that's supposed to implement `distclean`... very curious to see what it should be (I'm sure there's some macro that generates it for you)

Comment: Diff the generated files from the first time against the generated files from the second time and see what is different? (Since something must be different if the second time doesn't generate those warnings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to run **autoreconf -ivf**. I always create **autogen.sh** script in each project with the following content.

```
#!/bin/sh

autoreconf -ivf
```